# Update Azure Key Vault Secret using Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using Service Principal for Azure DevOps Release Pipeline and Azure VM as an agent pool.

But I'm getting an error like this `ERROR: Please run 'az login' to set up an account`.

My Pipeline looks like this :

```
variables:
  secretConfluentApiKey: 'ConfluentAPIKey'
  secretConfluentApiSecret: 'ConfluentAPISecret'

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Confluent: Kafka API Key Refresh'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure DevOps to Azure Resources'
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $env:path = $env:path + ";C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" + ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin"
     
     Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://keyserviceurlgoes.here" -OutFile C:\api-key
     Set-Location C:\
     $data = openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -in api-key -inkey my.key
     
     $SecretImport = $data | ConvertFrom-Json
     
     $Planned = (get-date $SecretImport.metadata.created_at).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'")
     
     $ConfluentAPIKey = "$(secretConfluentApiKey)"
     $ConfluentAPISecret = "$(secretConfluentApiSecret)"
     $ValutName = "$(azureKeyVaultName)"
     
     $CurrentKey = az keyvault secret show --name $ConfluentAPIKey --vault-name $ValutName --query "value"
     
     if ($CurrentKey -eq $SecretImport.key) {
         write-host 'Key is in Active State'
     }
     else {
     
         az keyvault secret set --vault-name $ValutName --name $ConfluentAPIKey --value $SecretImport.key --expires $Planned
     
         az keyvault secret set --vault-name $ValutName --name $ConfluentAPISecret --value $SecretImport.secret --expires $Planned
     }
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Please run ‘az login’ to set up an account

This error occurs when you are not logged into your Azure account and authenticated with it. Run this CLI task before running your key vault script. I created one Service Principal service connection in my Azure DevOps project and used it for authentication.

I added one Service Principal connection with my Service principal client Id, Tenant Id and Client secret like below:-

Project Settings > Service connections > New Service connection > Azure Resource Manager > Service connection (manual) > enter your service connection details like below:-

[image]

Enter service connection name > Verify and Save > Use this Service principal in your Azure CLI task for the key vault.

I ran the azure cli key vault script without running the az login --service principal command with service principal connection like below:-

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

trigger:

- main

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

steps:

- script: echo Hello, world!

displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

  

- script: |

echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.

echo See https://aka.ms/yaml

displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

  

- task: AzureCLI@2

inputs:

azureSubscription: 'ServicePrincipal'

scriptType: 'bash'

scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'

inlineScript: 'az keyvault secret set --name MySecretNamesiddesai --vault-name keyvaultname --value secretvalue'
```

[image]

Service principal connection was authenticated and new key vault secret was set like below:-

[image]

Even if using Service principal service connection fails, You can additionally run **az log in --service principal** command for the service principal in the CLI inline script like below:-

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2

inputs:

azureSubscription: 'ServicePrincipal'

scriptType: 'bash'

scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'

inlineScript: |

az login --service-principal -u <clientorappid> -p <client-secret> --tenant <tenant-id>

az keyvault secret set --name MySecretNamesid --vault-name keyvaultname --value keyvaultsecret
```

Output:-

[image]